# Preparing to switch to google compute engine for web hosting

Tags: google-compute-engine

Im currently in the process of switching to google compute engine for my web hosting because my current provider performance has been deteriorating over time. Giving me more flexibility to upgrade as I need to.

Ive got my website setup and working on the engine. But the next steps need to go smoothly to ensure my customers don't experience any downtime.

I have a few things I need to work out:

<s>- Does google have a way of managing email addresses at your own domain? Then I can just send or receive from gmail.com or another email client on my domain? Or do I have to setup a email server in my VM? If so is there any way to setup a cpanel like management software on it?</s>

<s>- To my understanding I should just have to call my current provider to ask them for my SSL certificates and for them to switch my domain over to google and then point it to my VM? or is there something I'm missing here?</s>

- Are there any simple ways to ensure my server says secure when I'm managing it myself other then just updating packages manually? Like a website I can use to track known security problems with the packages I have installed?

Edit:

Please read Dan Cornilescu's comment on this question about setting up your own custom domain email. He said it can possibly be managed using google apps.

On the topic of SSL/Domains I called my current provider and they said they would help me switch over if its what I decided. They also upgrading my hosting plan and things seem better now and are comparable to the performance I was getting on my google VM so Ill be trying that for now.

Comment: One possibility to use gmail with your own domain is via Google Apps: https://apps.google.com. I started directly on it, so I can't comment on switching over from another provider.

Comment: good to know. I called my other provider to talk to them about the domain and SSL certificates. They ended up upgrading my machine and I am now getting significantly better performance. So Ill be sticking with them for now.  Editing my question...